# useEffect hook runs infinitely when used in a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Below is my custom hook, I'm trying to handle everything from the hook. I have seen similar questions but none seems to work for my case and I have been made to believe there's a solution for this approach, jus can't figure it out.

```
const useResource = (baseUrl) => {
  const [resources, setResources] = useState([]);

  const create = async (resource) => {
    const response = await axios.post(baseUrl, resource)
    setResources(resources.concat(response.data));
    console.log(resources)
    return response.data
  }

  const get = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(baseUrl);
    setResources(response.data)
    return response.data
  }

  const service = {
    create,
    get
  }

  return [
    resources, service
  ]
}
```

Here is my approach to use the custom hook, but request keeps looping nonstop, please how do I stop it running after every render?

```
const App = () => {
  const content = useField('text');
  const name = useField('text');
  const number = useField('text');

  const [notes, noteService] = useResource('http://localhost:3005/notes');
  const [persons, personService] = useResource('http://localhost:3005/persons');
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    noteService.get();
  }, [noteService])

  useEffect(() => {
    personService.get();
  }, [personService])
  
  const handleNoteSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    noteService.create({ content: content.value });
  }

  const handlePersonSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    personService.create({ name: name.value, number: number.value});
  }
```

Edit: I just had to disable ESLint for the dependency line, because I just need it to run once after every render. Works well!

```
useEffect(() => {
    noteService.get();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    personService.get();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
```

Comment: `service` will be a new object each render. This will cause your useEffects that depend on them to also run each render.

Comment: @BrianThompson So what approach should I take, is it to remove the get request from the customer hook, please do explain.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out in comments, each time the component renders and calls your `useResource` hook, a new `service` object is created. If this `service` object is used as a dependency for any other hooks this will trigger their callbacks.

The solution is to memoize the `service` object so it's being provided as a stable reference. This can be accomplished via the `useMemo` hook. Because `service` will be memoized, the `create` callback will also be memoized and contain stale `resources` state. To address this update `create` to use a functional state update when appending new response data to the existing state.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';

const useResource = (baseUrl) => {
  const [resources, setResources] = useState([]);

  const create = async (resource) => {
    const response = await axios.post(baseUrl, resource);

    // Functional update to update from previous state
    setResources(resources => resources.concat(response.data));

    return response.data;
  }

  const get = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(baseUrl);
    setResources(response.data);
    return response.data;
  }

  const service = useMemo(() => ({
    create,
    get
  }), []);

  return [resources, service];
};
```

Comment: This answer is great, I only had to move the functions directly into the useMemo returned object, because of the Eslint dependency warning. Thank you